# What is this notification icon that looks like a raindrop?

Tags: notification-icons

My friend bought a Sony Xperia Z3, and started to install all the apps she liked. After installing dozens of apps, she realized that there is a notification icon looks like a raindrop. I was asked to get rid of it, but I couldn’t. I tried to stop all the running apps, but it remained on top. If she pulls down the notification bar, it shows nothing.

Any idea what this could be?status

[image: Raindrop status icon]

Comment: Hmm...I've done a Google image search and a TinEye image search and they haven't brought up anything related.  Do you have a list of possible apps it could be?

Comment: This looks like a shield with a keyhole, at least in such a small image. Have a look for  VPN Shield for Android on Google Play and on your device. - Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the list of currently running apps in Settings -> Apps  -> Running (could be different on Sony's devices.)

Narrow the list down by ignoring Google's and Sony's own services (e.g. Google Play serviced, Google Search, Google Keyboard, etc.)  Now examine each app that you don't recognize by taping on it, and tapping the "Stop" button.  If the icon on top disappears - that's the app which was spawning it.  You should now be able to open the app, go into its settings and look for a way to disable the notification icon.

If you are still unable to find the app after going through all 3rd-party apps, it's probably one of the system apps belonging to Sony.

Comment: Not really an answer, this should be a comment instead. Your answer is where they *might* look for the icon, but OP clearly stated "any idea what this could be?"  Besides OP already went to settings>apps>running> "I tried to stop all running app…" so would've seen the icon.